# Bukkit plugin get locations from config.yml

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create plugin, that will check when someone open the chest if the chest's location doesn't match with any location in my config.yml. So I want to do something like this:

```
ArratList<Location> list = new ArrayList();
foreach(get world, x, y, z from each key in section Locations in my config) {
    list.add(new Location(world, x, y, z));
    foreach(Location l : list) {
    if(l == p.location...
}
}
```

EDIT:
Now I have this code:

```
public class Listeners implements Listener {

    public Core plugin;
    public Listeners(Core core) {
        this.plugin = core;
    }

    @EventHandler
    private void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            if(plugin.createMode) {
                if (e.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.CHEST) {
                    e.setCancelled(true);
                    Location loc = e.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
                    String name = plugin.name;
                    plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".world", loc.getWorld().getName());
                    plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".x", loc.getBlockX());
                    plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".y", loc.getBlockY());
                    plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".z", loc.getBlockZ());
                    plugin.saveConfig();
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[ChestTreasure] " + ChatColor.RESET + "Treasury chest successfully created!");
                    plugin.createMode = false;
                }
            } else {
                if(e.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.CHEST) {
                    plugin.chests.clear();
                    for (String key : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(false) ){
                        //We are getting every key from our config.yml file
                        ConfigurationSection location = plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(key);
                        String world = location.getString(key + ".world");
                        int x = location.getInt(key + ".x");
                        int y = location.getInt(key + ".y");
                        int z = location.getInt(key + ".z");
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Hondnota x je " + String.valueOf(x));
                        Location l = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(world), x, y, z);
                        plugin.chests.add(l);
                    }
                    for(Location l : plugin.chests) {
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage(String.valueOf(e.getClickedBlock().getLocation().getX()));
                        if(l == e.getClickedBlock().getLocation()) {
                            e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Jeej");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I rightclick the chest, message jeej doesnt appear, everything what appears is message Hodnota x je 0. But I have several keys in my config and x is not 0 anywhere. In console this error appears:

```
[12:25:13 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to ChestTreasure v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:310) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:231) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:492) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:890) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(SourceFile:55) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(SourceFile:11) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:733) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:672) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:571) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null
        at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.getWorld(CraftServer.java:1023) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.getWorld(Bukkit.java:500) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at me.sudoman281.chestTreasure.Listeners.onPlayerInteract(Listeners.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: You appear to know what you want: "something like this". Apparently that's not enough and you want something more specific. You'll have to be more specific to explain us what you want exactly.

Comment: Please, state more clearly.

Comment: Can you get us which line is Listeners 47?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following:
Save your location in your configs as the following:

```
# CONFIG.YML #
location1:
 x: 0
 y: 0
 z: 0
 world: "world"
location2:
 x: ....
 .
 .
```

And then, to get all the configs we go:

```
ArrayList<Location> listLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();
for (String key : getConfig().getKeys(false) ){
    //We are getting every key from our config.yml file
    ConfigurationSection location = getConfig().getConfigurationSection(key);
    int x = location.getInt(key + ".x");
    int y = location.getInt(key + ".y");
    int z = location.getInt(key + ".z");
    String world = location.getString(key + ".world");
    Location l = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(world), x, y, z);
    listLocations.add(l);
}
```

You now should have all the locations that are on that config file to the ArrayList listLocations, and can make your checks from there!

Comment: But still have a problem, I have editted my question.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null | On line 47 in example. Could you give us that code as when I try to find line 47 I get a "}"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to get each individual value (x, y, z, world) from the config since:

[Location implements ConfigurationSerializable](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html), which means that you can just use `config#set("path.to.location", yourLocation);` and `yourLocation = (Location) config#get("path.to.location");`

---

Now, to your exception:

I suggest you [learn how to read stacktraces](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/fixing-plugin-problems-easily-reading-stacktraces/), as that would be very helpful to you in the future.

From these lines:

```
       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null
        at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.getWorld(CraftServer.java:1023) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.getWorld(Bukkit.java:500) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at me.sudoman281.chestTreasure.Listeners.onPlayerInteract(Listeners.java:47) ~[?:?]
```

I understand that you called `Bukkit.getWorld(null);` (indirectly), because world is null here `String world = location.getString(key + ".world");`
Check your config path, (However, I recommend you just use Location as I mentioned above)