# Bukkit plugin getting Location from config.yml

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have this code and I want when someone click the chest and it's location matches the location of clicked block to send player a message:

```
public class Listeners implements Listener {

public Core plugin;
public Listeners(Core core) {
    this.plugin = core;
}

@EventHandler
private void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
        if(plugin.createMode) {
            if (e.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.CHEST) {
                e.setCancelled(true);
                Location loc = e.getClickedBlock().getLocation();
                String name = plugin.name;
                plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".world", loc.getWorld().getName());
                plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".x", loc.getBlockX());
                plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".y", loc.getBlockY());
                plugin.getConfig().set(name + ".z", loc.getBlockZ());
                plugin.saveConfig();
                e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[ChestTreasure] " + ChatColor.RESET + "Treasury chest successfully created!");
                plugin.createMode = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(e.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.CHEST) {
                plugin.chests.clear();
                for (String key : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(false) ){
                    //We are getting every key from our config.yml file
                    ConfigurationSection location = plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(key);
                    String world = location.getString(key + ".world");
                    int x = location.getInt(key + ".x");
                    int y = location.getInt(key + ".y");
                    int z = location.getInt(key + ".z");
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Hondnota x je " + String.valueOf(x));
                    Location l = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(world), x, y, z);
                    plugin.chests.add(l);
                }
                for(Location l : plugin.chests) {
                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(String.valueOf(e.getClickedBlock().getLocation().getX()));
                    if(l == e.getClickedBlock().getLocation()) {
                        e.getPlayer().sendMessage("Jeej");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
But when I rightclick the chest, message jeej doesnt appear, everything what appears is message Hodnota x je 0. But I have several keys in my config and x is not 0 anywhere. In console this error appears:

```
[12:25:13 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to ChestTreasure v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:310) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:231) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:492) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:890) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(SourceFile:55) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(SourceFile:11) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:733) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:672) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_10_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:571) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null
        at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.getWorld(CraftServer.java:1023) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.getWorld(Bukkit.java:500) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at me.sudoman281.chestTreasure.Listeners.onPlayerInteract(Listeners.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bukkit plugin get locations from config.yml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797140/bukkit-plugin-get-locations-from-config-yml)

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null
        at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.CraftServer.getWorld(CraftServer.java:1023) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.getWorld(Bukkit.java:500) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-5391d73-0ebb9c7]
        at me.sudoman281.chestTreasure.Listeners.onPlayerInteract(Listeners.java:47) ~[?:?]
```

I didn't really have to read further than this to know that something in your onPlayerInteract is null, and it has something to do with getWorld, therefore, without much more information, I am pretty sure that this line is a problem:

```
Location l = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(world), x, y, z);
```

I guess your variable `world` is null, and since it's taken from the config, that most likely means that that it doesn't exist in config. 
These lines is most likely the issue:

```
for (String key : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(false) ){
                    //We are getting every key from our config.yml file
                    ConfigurationSection location = plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(key)
```

You are getting a ConfigurationSection for each of the keys. But those are most likely not ConfigurationSections. I believe you have a ConfigurationSection called location or something, if that's the case, you should do like so:

```
ConfigurationSection location = plugin.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("location")
```

instead.

I'm not sure if you're configurationsection is called location, but that's my guess, just replace location with the name of your actual section.

Without knowing how your config looks, this is the best I can answer